# How to implement searching of a string in dictionary plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, search, dictionary

I try it all day but method of Search Display Delegate Methods doesn't work.

I have a tableview that loads plist, and I am trying to implement search function.

Here is my code

```
#import "TabelViewController.h"
#import "Cell.h"
 @interface TabelViewController ()

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSDictionary *names;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSArray *keys;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSArray *FIOArray;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSMutableArray *filtredNames;
@property (nonatomic,copy) UISearchDisplayController *searchController;

@end
```

Method that dosent work correctly.
I don't know how to load correctly dictionaries from my plist to implement searching

```
  -(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{

[filtredNames removeAllObjects];

if (searchString.length > 0) {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchBar.text];


    for (NSString *key in keys ){

        NSArray *matches = [names[key]  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


        [filtredNames addObjectsFromArray:matches];

    }

     }
    return YES;
 }
```

Plist structure

```
<plist version="1.0">
          <dict>
<key>А</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>ФИО</key>
        <string>Аетров А.В.</string>
        <key>Доклад</key>
        <string>Доклад 5</string>
        <key>Время</key>
        <string>10:00-10:30</string>
        <key>День</key>
        <string>Четверг</string>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code will load your plist to dictionary:

```
NSString * filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Your_actual_file_name" ofType:@"plist"];
names = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSMutableArray * allValues = [NSMutableArray new];

for (NSArray * array in dict.allValues) {
    [allValues addObjectsFromArray:array];
}

FIOArray = allValues;
```

then your search method will be looks like:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString{

 [filtredNames removeAllObjects];

 if (searchString.length > 0) {

    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", searchString];
    NSArray *matches = [FIOArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    [filtredNames addObjectsFromArray:matches];

   }
 return YES;
 }
```

Comment: Thx but it also docent work. I think my mistake in this lines '   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [search] %@", self.searchBar.text];


    for (NSString *key in keys ){

        NSArray *matches = [names[key]  filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];


        [filtredNames addObjectsFromArray:matches];

    }
'

Comment: @Анвар, just copy whole `-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:` method from my answer, and code that load plist into dictionary too. its working, i checked it. Because in your case and see code where you get values for `keys` array, so if you don't - it would not work!

Comment: I did it with  
        for (NSString *key in keys ){

            FIOArray = [ names[key]  valueForKey :@"ФИО"];
              
         NSArray *matches = [ FIOArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
           
           [filtredNames addObjectsFromArray:matches];
sorry for your time

Comment: I am glad that you did it)